# Should I toString() before I parseFloat() in javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing

I have a value in my project that I need to parseFloat(). The trick is that the value may be null, int or a string, but it will always be a number. My question is, is it best practice to toString() my value before parseFloat().

.ex:

```
var num = null;

num = parseFloat(num.toString())
```

Would this be correct, or should I just do this?:

```
var num = null;

num = parseFloat(num)
```

Comment: parseFloat(null) = NaN so you should either check that "num" is null *before* calling parseFloat(), OR check that the parsed value isNan() and treat that case correctly in your code. In either case, there's no need to call .toString()

Comment: So how does `null` count as a number? What number would it be?

Comment: What are you doing with `num` after you parsed it? What is its purpose?

Comment: Let me be completely honest I am a javascript and C# programmer, and have been programming a few years. I ask this question because my boss and I were arguing. He says that no matter what you should always cast a property before trying to parse it no matter the case. I said that is true in C#, but not in javascript. I just wanted to settle this with the help of some fellow programmers. What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to the ECMAScript 5.1 specification](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.3), `parseFloat()` implicitly calls the internal function `ToString()` on its argument before processing it. The said function [properly handles values such as `undefined` or `null`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8).

No, you don't have to call `toString()` yourself, the conversion is implied by `parseFloat()` and it covers a broader range of values (`toString()` is not available on variables of certain types, such as `null`).

Answer (score 1):

Null does not have a toString() method.

```
var num = null;
//....
// operate on num
//....
if (!num) {
  num = parseFloat(0);
} else {
  num = parseFloat(num);
}
```

If the first nonspace character in the string generated by `num.toString()` is not part of a numeric literal, `parseFloat()` will return NaN. If you don't want NaN values in your data, you'll have to check for this.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript will automaticlly convert any number to a string, so toString() is not necessary. You should be aware that if num is null NaN string is return.